# does text-indent also indents <img>?

Tags: css, image, text-indent

i'm trying to use CSS to replace the image in html, so

```
<img class="flechaTooltip" src="oldpath" />

turns into

    .flechaTooltip {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 11px 209px 0 0; /* New image's dimensions here */
    background: url(../../nImg/flechaTooltipGris.gif) no-repeat;
    /* Removing image from older Opera */
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to make any effect, any idea why??

-edit-

i have used this technique to replace text for an img, but never tried to replace img for another img

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text-indent` only works on inline elements in the flow, so if you'd use it for a line with inline  element (or any other inline or inline-block elements) it would work.

However, you can replace an image with another image using CSS if you know the new image's dimensions using the following CSS:

```
.flechaTooltip {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 50px 300px 0 0; /* New image's dimensions here */
    background: url(newpath);
    /* Removing image from older Opera */
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/kNAgT/4/

Comment: Yeah, however, it's good that you mentioned this: I remebered that older Opera had some issues with that, so I updated my code, including the fix for it (it's safe to use it in other browsers in main css, so no need in hacks).

Comment: please check this out http://keepyourlinks.com/uploads/284/Dibujo_2.JPG mi intention its to remove the blue one and display the greyone (newpath) where the blue one is, i will place the CSS in the question

Comment: That's strange — can you reproduce it on jsfiddle or share a link to the markup with the problem, so I could find what's wrong with it?

Comment: unfortunatelly i can't... but if I do background: url(../../nImg/flechaTooltipGris.gif) no-repeat bottom left; then i don't see the grey one (i asume this behind) even if I z-index: 9999; any idea??

Comment: It looks like some other styles are overriding the styles for `.flechaTooltip`, you can try to find them in Firebug/Inspector (or other tool for debugging CSS), or add `!important` to `width`,`height` and `padding` properties (like `width: 0 !important;` etc.).

Comment: this way... http://keepyourlinks.com/files/461/dibujo3jpg looks like we are getting closer! but the image it's not completelly visible :?

Comment: hey!!! :D:D forget about it! i had the wrong padding width (209 instead of 229); i will just make sure it works in all browsers

Comment: well, it looks perfect in all browsers (even IE6) except IE7 (weird) http://keepyourlinks.com/files/462/dibujo4jpg what hack shall i use? tried margin-bottom:-2px; and padding-bottom:-2px with no success... any suggestion? thanks again ! -EEEDIIT- got it: *+ html .flechaTooltip { position:relative; bottom:-3px;} doesn't look really good dough...

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't... because an image contains no text to indent.

However, you can achieve the affect you want by wrapping the image in another element, like a `p` or `div`.

So

`<p class="flechaTooltip"><img src="oldpath" /></p>`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/v7GyN/

Comment: I see, my question was because i was trying to do what i need editing only the CSS (external reasons), thanks!